# Why setting windowLightStatusBar ain't working programmatically using WindowInsetsControllerCompat#setAppearanceLightStatusBars()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-statusbar

I'm trying to create a launcher app, but i had problem when trying to change `windowLightStatusBar` programmatically on API 30 and the same code works perfectly fine bellow that, i hope if someone can help me out:)

Here is the full class source code:

```java
public final class AppDrawer extends BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback implements OnApplyWindowInsetsListener {

    private static boolean ALREADY_CREATED = false;

    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    private boolean dragging = false;
    private float radius;
    private int left, right, height, peekOver, oldState;
    private Rect displayRect = new Rect();
    private DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    private Insets navigationBarInsets = Insets.of(0, 0, 0, 0), cutoutInsets = navigationBarInsets;
    private WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController;
    private Configuration oldConfiguration;
    private CardView cardView;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private BottomSheetBehavior<FrameLayout> bottomSheetBehavior;

    public AppDrawer(AppCompatActivity activity){
        if(ALREADY_CREATED) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The appDrawer object cannot be created more than once, clear the existing one from the memory first.");
        this.activity = activity;
        ALREADY_CREATED = true;
    }

    public void destroy(){
        activity = null;
        radius = 0.0f;
        left = right = height = peekOver = oldState = 0;
        displayRect = null;
        displayMetrics = null;
        navigationBarInsets = cutoutInsets = navigationBarInsets = null;
        windowInsetsController = null;
        oldConfiguration = null;
        cardView = null;
        frameLayout = null;
        bottomSheetBehavior = null;
        ALREADY_CREATED = false;
    }
    // WindowInsetControllerCompat is created and set from the activity that created this class
    public void setWindowInsetsController(@NonNull WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController) { this.windowInsetsController = windowInsetsController; }

    public void initViews(View contentView){

        oldConfiguration = activity.getResources().getConfiguration();
        cardView = activity.findViewById(R.id.app_drawer_card_view);
        frameLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.app_drawer_container);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(frameLayout);

        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(this);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(contentView, this);

        updateVars();
    }

    @Override
    public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
        if(dragging) return insets;
        cutoutInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.displayCutout());
        navigationBarInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars());
        updateVars();
        if(bottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) frameLayout.setPadding(left + navigationBarInsets.left, 0, right + navigationBarInsets.right, 0);
        return insets;
    }

    public void setConfiguration(Configuration configuration) { this.oldConfiguration = configuration; }

    private void updateWindowInsetsBars(int state){
        // here is the one i used
        if (state != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED && (oldConfiguration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO) {
            windowInsetsController.setAppearanceLightNavigationBars(true);
            windowInsetsController.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);
        } else {
            windowInsetsController.setAppearanceLightNavigationBars(false);
            windowInsetsController.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(false);
        }

        // here is the one of @Zain answer
        if (state != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED && (oldConfiguration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO) {
            new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(activity.getWindow(), activity.getWindow().getDecorView()).setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);
            new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(activity.getWindow(), activity.getWindow().getDecorView()).setAppearanceLightNavigationBars(true);
        } else {
            new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(activity.getWindow(), activity.getWindow().getDecorView()).setAppearanceLightStatusBars(false);
            new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(activity.getWindow(), activity.getWindow().getDecorView()).setAppearanceLightNavigationBars(false);
        }


    }

    private void updateCardViewState(float slideOffset){
        float a = 1.f - slideOffset;
        cardView.setRadius(radius * a);
        frameLayout.setPadding((int) ((left + navigationBarInsets.left) * a) , 0, (int) ((right + navigationBarInsets.right) * a), 0);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) cardView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = (int) ((displayRect.height() + navigationBarInsets.bottom + cutoutInsets.top + cutoutInsets.bottom) * slideOffset + height * a);
        Log.d("AppDrawer", "card height: " + layoutParams.height + ", screen height: " + displayRect.height());
        //cardView.setAlpha(Math.min(slideOffset * 1.1f, 1.0f));
        cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    private void updateDisplayMetrics(){
        WindowManager windowManager = this.activity.getWindowManager();
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
            displayRect.set(windowManager.getCurrentWindowMetrics().getBounds());
            displayRect.bottom -= navigationBarInsets.bottom + cutoutInsets.top + cutoutInsets.bottom;
            displayRect.right -= navigationBarInsets.right + cutoutInsets.left + cutoutInsets.right;
        } else {
            displayRect.top = 0;
            displayRect.bottom = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            displayRect.left = 0;
            displayRect.right = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        }
    }

    private void updateVars(){
        updateDisplayMetrics();
        peekOver = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10f, displayMetrics);
        radius = radius == 0 ? cardView.getRadius() : radius;
        left = left == 0 ? frameLayout.getPaddingLeft() : left;
        right = right == 0 ? frameLayout.getPaddingRight() : right;
        height = height == 0 ? cardView.getLayoutParams().height : height;
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(height + navigationBarInsets.bottom + peekOver);
        if(oldState != 0) updateCardViewState(oldState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED ? 0.0f : 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        dragging = newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING;
        updateWindowInsetsBars(newState);
        oldState = newState;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) { updateCardViewState(slideOffset); }
}
```

Here you can see on API 30 that the `navigationbar` is white while the `statusbar` still black, even tho both are set to `false` but it doesn't effect the `statusbar` at all.

[Screenshot-1 on API 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FjSI.png)

[Screenshot-2 on API 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpe9a.png)

But here on API 29 (it works fine below that too) that they are both changes fine.

[Screenshot-1 on API 29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0MHN.png)

[Screenshot-2 on API 29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K4Mv.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a platform bug.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180881870

To fix this issue you should just update your `androidx.core:core-ktx` to version `1.8.0-alpha03` or higher.

Pls refer to api changes for details
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.8.0-alpha03

Answer (score 1):

For me it's because of this:

```xml
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
```

This is prevent me to make change to status bar text color programmatically! After I remove this, I can change status bar text color programmatically again! I hope this is useful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution:**

after a bit of testing different stuff i found what caused that problem.

```java
/* make system bars transparent */
private void setup(){
    Window window = getWindow();

    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);

    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.getDecorView());

    windowInsetsController.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars() | WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());

    appDrawer.setWindowInsetsController(windowInsetsController);

}
```

In that method `setup()` that makes the status/navigation bar transparent when activity calls `onCreate()` method, well everything is fine except one thing and that i didn't set `window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);` after doing so, the status bar changes just fine.
Here is the new code:

```java
/* make system bars transparent */
private void setup(){
    Window window = getWindow();

    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);

    // Adding it fix the problem.
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);

    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.getDecorView());

    windowInsetsController.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars() | WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());

    appDrawer.setWindowInsetsController(windowInsetsController);

}
```

Hopefully someone will find this useful, and doesn't make the same silly mistake as i did

**UPDATE:**

I found out what really caused the problem, is it adding:

```xml
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

to the themes.xml file makes setting `statusbar` to light programmatically not working, i don't know what make that causes the problem but now that i know it, i don't have to use `window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);` since it is deprecated on API 30 and above as [@Zain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9851608/zain) pointed out.

Comment: Great that you found it, but I see that these are deprecated APIs although they are still working on API-30+, but soon or later will not.

Comment: Yes you're right and i figured out that what caused the problem is setting `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` i don't know why but removing it make it work without using `window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);`, i might as well add that to the anwser